# How to access Android PackageMananger in unity?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game for android. Is there any way to access android package manager(android.content.pm.PackageManager) in unity and run the following Java codes on unity's c# script?

```
  final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  // get the list of all installed apps on the device.
  List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

I need to get all the package names on the device.

The documentaion says we should use AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject but I still don't know how to use them.
[https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-plugins-java-code-from-c-sharp.html](https://stackoverflow.com)